# Efficient way to pivot table

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table named monthly_agg which contains monthly aggregated data.

```
+------------+-----+----------+-----------+---------------+--------------+-------------+----------+---------+
| yyyy_mm_dd | id  | app      | ex_status | active_status | active_count | active_base | ex_count | ex_base |
+------------+-----+----------+-----------+---------------+--------------+-------------+----------+---------+
| 2019-01-31 | 123 | content  | impl      | impl          | 390          | 321         | 344      | 340     |
+------------+-----+----------+-----------+---------------+--------------+-------------+----------+---------+
| 2019-01-31 | 333 | messages | impl      | impl          | 541          | 210         | 788      | 610     |
+------------+-----+----------+-----------+---------------+--------------+-------------+----------+---------+
| 2019-01-31 | 832 | photos   | no        | no            | null         | 430         | null     | 100     |
+------------+-----+----------+-----------+---------------+--------------+-------------+----------+---------+
```

I want to make each app, be a column. Each app column should contain a percentage, which is calculated as follows:

```
SELECT 
    yyyy_mm_dd,
    id,
   App,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN (app = ‘content’ AND ex_status = ‘impl’) THEN ex_count/ex_base
        WHEN (active_status = 'impl') THEN active_count/active_base
    END) AS percentage
FROM 
    monthly_agg
```

I need to have each `app` value to be be a column and then the value of that column be the result of the above calculation. How could I pivot the table this way? Ideally my output would look like this:

```
+------------+-----+--------------------+---------------------+
| yyyy_mm_dd | id  | content_percentage | messages_percentage |
+------------+-----+--------------------+---------------------+
| 2019-01-31 | 123 | 1.2                | null                |
+------------+-----+--------------------+---------------------+
| 2019-01-31 | 333 | null               | 2.57                |
+------------+-----+--------------------+---------------------+
```

I have about 20 apps so being dynamic would be great.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC You can try:

```sql
SELECT 
    yyyy_mm_dd,
    id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (app = 'content' AND ex_status = 'impl') THEN ex_count/ex_base 
WHEN (app = 'content' and active_status = 'impl') THEN active_count/active_base ELSE 0 END) AS content_percentage,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (app = 'messages' and active_status = 'impl') THEN active_count/active_base ELSE 0 END) AS messages_percentage
FROM 
    monthly_agg
GROUP BY
    yyyy_mm_dd, id
```

Comment: With this approach, I would need a case statement  for every `app`. If more were added in the future, then the query would need to be modified. Is there a way to achieve this more dynamically?

Comment: Hm, I would do combination of shell with hive, or (way better solution) employ pyspark/pandas. Hive on it's own won't provide you with such generic approach.

Comment: HiveQL doesn't support dynamic pivot like you describe. If you want to do something like this you need to use straight dynamic SQL and construct the query in whatever orchestration tool you're using. 
Personally I have always done this type of query construction in Spark, which I use to drive all my operations.

Comment: Which is literally what I said :) alternatively bash + hive would do as well